# Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found error in Phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to convert excel file directly to PDF with the help of PHPSpreadsheet. but got an error "**Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found**", Here is my code:

```
<?php 
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf;

  $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
  $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
  $spreadsheet = $reader->load("excel.xlsx");


  // when I use this MPDF class, I'm getting an error Class \Mpdf\Mpdf not found

  $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf($spreadsheet);
  $writer->save("excel.pdf");
```

Kindly Help with above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#pdf) of phpspreadsheet:

> You must now install a PDF rendering library yourself; but PhpSpreadsheet will work with a number of different libraries.

The error comes from not installing the rendering library you want to use (in this case mPDF). Just add [`mpdf/mpdf`](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf) to your composer dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for reply @BlobbyBob. I was installed PHPSpreadsheet with composer and all there pdf library also install withing phpspreadsheet.

Comment: Apparently it isn't correctly installed because `\Mpdf\Mpdf` can't be found. Try to add it manually and run `composer update`

Comment: @ArunKumar You shouldn't put it manually in any directory. Just run `composer require mpdf/mpdf` and everything should work

Comment: @BlobbBob My excel file convert successfully to pdf but I'm Getting "Warning: unlink(C:\Windows\Temp\ib9CEB.tmp): Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\api\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Cache.php on line 69" error.